# Multiple images preview are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filereader

This code is displaying only single selected image. The last image selected in the list. I think either loop position is not correct or append code is not correct. I have tried with changing positions also but same thing only single image is showing.

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader(),
    count = input.files.length;
    for(i=0;i<=count;i++){
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        //$('.image_preview_cont').html('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" />');
        $('.image_preview_cont').append('<img src="#" id="img_preview'+i+'" />');
        $('#img_preview'+i).attr('src',e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdhead">Product Image</td><td><input type="file" name="p_image[]" 
    id="imgInp[]" multiple="true" onchange="readURL(this)" /><td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="image_preview_cont"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: check i inside reader.onload function

Comment: there are two "i" inside reader.onload function @Dart

Comment: u shouldn't rely on "i" inside reader.onload, better count imgs inside .image_preview_cont, and use this count value instead of "i". Because reader.readAsDataURL will be executed asynchronously(AFAIK)

Comment: no nothing is happen with removing "i" also. Can you suggest answer with code @Dart

Comment: here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/10r0kdex/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are repeatedly replacing the `onload` handler of a single `reader`, and you're not waiting for one image to load before changing the URI.  So you only ever process one image.

In addition, when your `onload` handler gets around to executing it is likely that `i` will be equal to `count` because it is executed asynchronously and you're stopping the `for` loop one step after you've reached the end of the zero-indexed array.

All this becomes clear with addition of [a few `console.log()` statements](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/10r0kdex/):

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an object.
"Count: 3"
"readUrl: 0"
"readUrl: 1"
"readUrl: 2"
"readUrl: 3"
"onload: 3"
```

So the obvious fix is not to do those things.  First, create your load handler as a separate function which doesn't depend on the `i` in the `for` loop, then you can reuse it:

```
function loadReader(e) {
    var i = $('.image_preview_cont img').length;
    $('.image_preview_cont').append('<img src="#" id="img_preview'+i+'" />');
    $('#img_preview'+i).attr('src',e.target.result);
}
```

Then, instead of having one `FileReader`, create an array to hold several in (one for each image):

```
var readers = [],
    count = input.files.length;
```

Finally, fix the termination condition of the `for` loop and create the `FileReader` objects inside of it:

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    readers[i] = new FileReader();
    readers[i].onload = loadReader;
    readers[i].readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/10r0kdex/1/).